# React Native: Android Build Failed. Task :react-native-keychain:parseDebugLocalResources FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

we unable to build the android build.

> Task :react-native-keychain:parseDebugLocalResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-keychain:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-keychain:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar

Package.json React version detail:
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.0",
"react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6"

Android-build.gradle detail:

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 31
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
  dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31")
        
}
```